# react route not found shows up on every route even with using switch

Tags: reactjs, react-router

Here's my routing configuration below. My issue is the last route: Not Found shows up on every route.

Kindly let me know where I'm doing wrong.

```
<HashRouter>
  <Switch>
    <MainWrapper>
      <Route exact path="/" component={Search} />
      <Route exact path="/search" component={Search} />
      <Route exact path="/records" exact component={Records} />
      <Route exact path="/records/:id" component={Records} />
  <Route exact path="/newrecord" component={NewRecord} />
  <Route exact path="/newrecord/:id" component={NewRecord} />

  <Route exact path="/newField" component={NewFields} />
  <Route exact path="/newfield/:id" component={NewFields} />
  <Route exact path="/newfield/:id/:recordId" component={NewFields} />

  <Route exact path="/editrecords" component={EditRecords} />
  <Route exact path="/editrecords/:id" component={EditRecords} />

  />
  <Route exact path="/RecentlyCreatedTemplates" component=

  <Route component={NotFound} />

</MainWrapper>
</Switch>
</HashRouter>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Place the `<Switch>` inside the `<MainWrapper>` tag, because Switch will scan it's route direct children (things might get messed up when inserting a High Order Component between Switch and Route)